# Interpolating a shell command into an ansible command string

Tags: ansible

Say I have the following ansible command that adds the docker repository to apt

```
- name: Add Docker Repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable
    state: present
```

I'd love the command to automatically determine the version since I might not always run this on `xenial`. So I tried the following:

```
- name: Add Docker Repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable
    state: present
```

But I get an error: `E:Failed to fetch https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/$(lsb_release/-cs)/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found`

What's the right way to escape the`$(..)` so that it evaluates correctly in bash before the command is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you could do is have a previous task that registers the output from "lsb_release -cs" and saves that in a variable:

```
- name: Register Ubuntu version
  command: lsb_release -cs
  register: your_variable_name
```

To access the value simply look for the your_variable_name.stdout, like so:

```
- name: Add Docker Repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{ your_variable_name.stdout }} stable
    state: present
```

If you'd like to see every detail about that variable:

```
- name: Inspect variable
  debug:
    var: your_variable_name
```

Edit: Just beware of the formatting on your url string, my answer is just an example, you may have to trim some whitespaces or add some "/" to achieve what you want ^^

Answer (score 1):

According to this [collection link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pipe_lookup.html), you can use {{lookup('pipe', '***command***')}}. It returns the stdout from command.

For example:

```
- name: Install Docker-Compose
  get_url:
    url: "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.24.7/docker-compose-{{lookup('pipe', 'uname -s')}}-{{lookup('pipe', 'uname -m')}}"
    dest: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    mode: +x
```

In your case:

```
- name: Add Docker Repository
  apt_repository:
    repo: deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu {{lookup('pipe', 'lsb_release -cs')}} stable
    state: present
```